# Getting Error on implementing Dismissible on flutter list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I am trying to implement `Dismissible` to swipe and remove the item from the list in flutter, but I am getting the below error on implementation of the same

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of
> type 'String'

at this line of the code `key: Key(item)`

How should I resolve it ?

```
            ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index){
                return Divider();
              },
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: noteItems,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                final item = firstdata[index];
                return 
                  Dismissible(
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  key: Key(item),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      firstdata.removeAt(index);
                    });
                    Scaffold.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
                  },
                  background: Container(color: Colors.red)
                  ,

                  child: Padding(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 7.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        ListTile(
                          
                          leading:ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Image.asset('images/appstore.png', width: 50, height: 50)
                          ) ,

                          title:
                          Row(children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: firstdata[index]['id']!= null?AutoSizeText(
                                firstdata[index]['id'],
                                maxLines: 2,


                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),) :Text(''),
                            ),

                          ],),



                        ),







                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );

              },

            ),
```

The JSON data structure for the list view is here below

```
  {
    "error": "false",
    "notification": [
        {
            "rn": "1",
            "id": "224",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "2",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "2",
            "id": "219",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "3",
            "id": "213",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "4",
            "id": "209",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "4",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "5",
            "id": "204",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "6",
            "id": "199",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "7",
            "id": "193",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

How should I implement the same and get it resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the other answer, the Key function expects a string to create a key based on that. If you can identify an item based on one of its parameters (for example `id`), then you could use `item.id` and it would be fine.

However, to make sure it will be truly unique key for any combination of parameters (in your case `id`, `rn` and `company_details`) you can use [ObjectKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ObjectKey-class.html):

Replace the following line:

```
key: Key(item)
```

With the following:

```
key:ObjectKey(item)
```

This way Flutter can identify your item's parameters and create a key based on the combination of them.

Other options include [ValueKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueKey-class.html) and [UniqueKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

means that it crashed because it was expecting a String and flutter did not find one.

This means that:

`key: Key(item)`

Key(item)-> Is not a String. I don´t know how are you creating Key/where is it.

My best guess is to try to find some method like...:

```
`key: Key(item).aMethodthatgivesaString()`
`key: Key(item).toString()`
```

Let me know if this was useful.